# How to block a background thread until the main run loop sleeps?

Tags: ios, multithreading, runloop

I  wish to block a background thread until my main thread's run loop is sleeping (aka the main thread is waiting for input).

I think I can do this by doing:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(waitSelector) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:TRUE];
```

However I do believe there is probably a better way of doing this. Any advice?

Comment: What do you do in `waitSelector` ?

Comment: nothing, i was just using the waitUntilDone aspect

Comment: So basically, you just want to wait until the next run loop?

Comment: well not really, right now I am triggering the next run loop on the main thread by performing a selector on the main thread.  In an optimal scenario I wouldn't trigger the next run loop, just wait for the current one to finish on the main thread.  Since a run loop is mostly sleeping until input triggers it, I would like to wait in my background thread till the next time the main thread run loop is sleeping without triggering a cycle on the main thread run loop.